# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los atributos src y data-src?

Tags: html, imagen, atributos, src

¿Cuáles son las diferencias y consecuencias (tanto buenas como malas) de usar el atributo data-src o src de la etiqueta img? ¿Puedo lograr los mismos resultados con ambos? Si es así, ¿cuándo debe usarse cada uno de ellos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los atributos '**src**' y '**data-src**' no tienen nada en común, excepto que ambos están permitidos por 'HTML5 CR' y ambos contienen las letras 'src'. Todo lo demás es diferente.

El atributo '**src**' se define en las especificaciones 'HTML' y tiene un significado funcional.

El atributo '**data-src**' es solo uno del conjunto infinito de atributos '**data- ***', que no tienen un significado definido, pero que se pueden usar para incluir datos invisibles en un elemento, para usar en secuencias de comandos (o estilos).

PD: Esto es un traducción de la pregunta y respuesta de la versión en inglés de SO que se encuentra en la siguiente url: [What are all the differences between src and data-src attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320052/what-are-all-the-differences-between-src-and-data-src-attributes/15320346)

Me ha parecido interesante compartir esta información ya que algunas personas me han planteado la cuestión en varias ocasiones y a mi personalmente en su día me ayudó.

Incluyo otro enlace a la documentación sobre atributos 'data-*': [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)